# Web service call returns "Fault string, and possibly fault code, not set"

Tags: java, web-services, soap-client

I have a java application (**A**) that calls the webservice.

1)Then I have another app (**B**) that uses the **A** jar.
The call is successful and needed data are returned.

2)Then I have web application that also uses the **A** jar.
In this case when the web service method is called from A app, an exception is thrown.

Since the class that executes the webservice call is the same in both cases, I'm not sure where the problem is.
The webservice is on https server. But I authenticate using credentials.

I think maybe something should be set in the web application, but I don't know what..

The exception is:

```
09:21:48.009 [http-nio-8084-exec-33] WARN  o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://www.myserver.com/ci}ci2#{http://www.myserver.com/ci}GetCertPath has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:209) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.setSoapAction(SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.java:122) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Fault string, and possibly fault code, not set
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.java:63) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:158)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.java:47) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) ~[cxf-api-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572) [cxf-api-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481) [cxf-api-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382) [cxf-api-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy318.getCertPath(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335) [cxf-api-2.7.16.jar:2.7.16]
..... more lines here :) .....
    at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:209)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.setSoapAction(SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.java:122)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.java:63)
Fault string, and possibly fault code, not set
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
    ... 59 more
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

EDIT:
Does it have to have any headers set? When connecting in case 1, there is nothing specific set and it's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I have found the issue. The request should have included the content-type. Which is strange that it didn't threw an exception in the first case...

I have added `Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8` and the web application is working too.

As I found out the j`avax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Fault string, and possibly fault code, not set` is mostly connected to missing content-type..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was due to a simple badly formatted URL in a placeholder. http:/xxx.yyu (note the single /)

CXF wasn't very clear running in JDK6 but running in JDK8 was more explicit